# Unable to obtain individual IDs for generated lines from WhiteboxTool TraceDownslopeFlowpaths

Tags: qgis, whitebox-gat, whitebox-tools

I am using the Whitebox Tools (2.0.0 - guessing?) in QGIS (3.20.3) and using the TraceDownslopeFlowpaths process to obtain flow lines from points.

When these are generated, all starting lines (i.e. the first line which does not have a connecting line upstream) starts with 1, then the numbers increase as they connect with lines downstream (2, 3, 4 etc.).

I want all lines to have individual IDs as I need to use the individual lines for further analysis.

Is there a way to do this?

**What I've tried:**

Adding individual IDs to the seed points - does not generate individual IDs for the generated lines.

Converting seed points to raster with increasing values to act as ID. Still does not work as it will not take the raster for the seed points - even thought I read somewhere it would.

Comment: But what would you do when two lines intersect? Which ID should continue on downslope of the intersection?

Comment: I would have hoped it would have combined them and created a summed number. Or maybe could chose what fields to use and how you would want them intersects to be dealt with. Maybe I was hoping for too much haha.

Comment: ID values are just labels. I don't think it would be a good idea to treat them like numbers and to sum them. For example when flow path 1 and 2 intersect, you would have 3 carry on downslope. But there may already be an ID 3 in the data.